# OVS for Office 2010 - Macs?

Tags: mac-osx, licensing, microsoft-office-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We're right in the middle of planning/buying Office 2010 for our main office. We have a mixed enviroment with Office 2003 and Office 2004 Mac Edition.

I've called both my reseller and Microsoft directly, but I'm always redirected to some (insert bad word here) who doesn't know the answer to this question:

If I buy x number of Office Professional Plus licenses with software assurance - can I safely assume that I can use some of them on Macs (Office 2008 for Mac right now, and then to Office 2011 for Mac when it's released)?

I've downloaded a white paper from Microsoft (dated 2008, so I don't know if it still applies), and it says this:

> When acquired under a Volume Licensing agreement, some licenses for the Microsoft Office system products are considered Platform Independent Licenses. These include Microsoft Office Standard 2007 for Windows, Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007, Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007, Office for Mac, and the individual Microsoft Office system programs: Microsoft Office Word 2007, Microsoft Office Excel® 2007 spreadsheet software, and Microsoft Office PowerPoint® 2007 presentation graphics program for both Windows and Mac.
>   Software under a Platform Independent License may be used on any computer platform (e.g., PC, Mac) as long as the version being used is the same or earlier than the originally licensed product version. For example, a customer with a license for Office Standard 2007 for Windows can use Office Standard 2003 for Windows or Office 2004 for Mac but cannot use Office 2008 for Mac. The exception is if the customer has had active Software Assurance coverage on their Office Standard 2007 for Windows license at the time of Office 2008 for Mac release.

Comment: On a side note: I hate licensing. Someone at Microsoft is going to hell for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wanted to buy Mac Versions with SA from MS. We got a Licens Contract and Login to the Licensecenter. There I can download Win and Mac Products. This was consulted by MS here in Austria directly.

Comment: Putting this as the correct answer, just got it confirmed from Microsoft that Office on a OVS agreement counts for both PC and Mac.